# Is a statement can be prove more than one methods by logical equivalences?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How long we should go to prove a statement by using logical equivalences and there can be more than one method to prove a statement using logical equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

1. As long as we need to.
2. Yes, of course.